# Would a statically sized Rcpp empty list be more efficient than list.push_back()?

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

If one wishes to iterate over a function and add the results to a list in Rcpp, one can use the `.push_back()` method, for example:

```
List appended_list() {
    List emptylist = List::create();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      emptylist.push_back(i);
    }
    return emptylist;
}
```

However, am I correct in saying that the list gets redefined each time and thus this method is very inefficient? Is there a way to instead create a list of a static size (ie. create a list of *n* elements, where each element is `NULL` or `NA` or some such)? For example, to do this in R one would write:

```
emptylist <- list()
length(emptylist) <- 3
for (i in 1:3) {
  emptylist[[i]] <- i
}
```

Is there a way to do this in Rcpp please? Would it be more efficient?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A pre-allocated list will be *much* faster.
If you are unsure how to create a list of pre-determined size,
my suggestion is that you probably need to spend some time with introductory Rcpp materials.
Some good resources are:

- The vignettes offered by `Rcpp`, in particular the Introduction and FAQ vignettes. In addition to accessing them from R, you can find them on the web [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/index.html)
- [Rcpp for everyone](https://teuder.github.io/rcpp4everyone_en/)
- [Hadley's chapter on Rcpp](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Rcpp.html)

Here is an example showing how much faster avoiding `push_back()` can be.
In `so.cpp`, we have

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void test1() {
    Rcpp::List out;
    for ( int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i ) {
        out.push_back(i);
    }
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void test2() {
    Rcpp::List out(1000);
    for ( int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i ) {
        out[i] = i;
    }
}
```

Then we benchmark the functions against each other:

```r
Rcpp::sourceCpp("so.cpp")
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(empty_list = test1(), pre_allocated = test2())

Unit: microseconds
          expr      min       lq       mean    median        uq      max
    empty_list 3553.549 3755.405 4337.71591 3894.3075 4106.7500 8790.787
 pre_allocated   22.089   23.689   38.67364   24.6645   26.1165 1339.443
 neval
   100
   100
```

So you can see there is a considerable difference there.
Of course, in this *simplified* case, it's a "considerable" difference that wouldn't be noticeable to humans, but in a more complex use case, or something that calls such a function many times, it could be actually "considerable."

Comment: Yay for empirics and _measurements_ trumping man yelling opinion at cloud ;-)

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware from using *Rcpp for Everyone* that the latter method was possible, I may have misread or misunderstood.

Comment: @GMSL You may be right that this particular issue isn't covered in that resource specifically. For myself, I came up learning R first, then ended up turning to C++ for more efficient computation in some projects; in the process of learning C++ on my own, I had to consult *multiple* resources, and frankly still consider myself to be a novice---I still consult more than one introductory resources on a weekly basis! I would strongly advise branching out in the resources you consult; in my experience no one of them alone really can have everything

Comment: Isn't that the case for _any_ topic?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Indeed

Answer (score 4):

As a general rule you *always* want to preallocate.

And yes, you rediscovered something ("`push_back` is expensive on R `SEXP` types") we documented for probably close to a decade. If you don't know your size beforehand, use a standard container from the STL instead (which have *much* better behavior when it comes to growing) and convert at the end.